# How to assign values to non single character then calculate the sum of the values when the characters are inputted in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I need to assign the values 3,4,6,7 and 9 to characters t1,t2,t3,t4 and t5 respectively, so that when you input some characters you can get the sum of the assigned values of those characters. for example if you enter t1t2 you get 7 or when input t1t3t4 you get 16 and so on. Below is the code that i tried but i realised that char variable only recognizes single character, but in my case all the characters are double characters (an alphabet and a number e.g t1) which i might need the use of string but i dont know how. any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char items[] = "t1t2t3t4t5";
int values[] = {3,4,6,7,9};
char entry[100];
std::cout<<"Enter an entry: ";
std::cin>> std::setw ( 100 ) >> entry;

int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; entry[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
for ( int j = 0; items[j] != '\0'; j++ ) {
if ( entry[i] == items[j] )
  sum += values[j];}
cout<< endl;     }
  std::cout<< "The sum is: "<<sum;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

the above code obviously does not treat my items as single character, it separate the ts with the numbers and treat them individually.

Comment: Try to use a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` instead of an array, which is easier to use for your purpose. Also you could store the values given by the user in a `std::vector<int>` instead of an array

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about c++ I would suggest you to use std::unordered_map  or std::map(the latter if you need the variables to be sorted).

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, int> marray;
marray["t1"] = 1;

....

std::string name;
int val;
std::cin >> name >> value;
marray[name] = value;
```